# Hook for adding values to add node page

Tags: nodes, 8, hooks

I'm searching for a hook in Drupal 8 API for adding values to a add content form.
What hook can I use to alter values from /node/add/movies_movie page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your module, there is a [your-module].module file where you can write `hook_form_alter()`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
 function module_name_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == 'node_movies_movie_form') {
     // Your code goes here.
     ...
     ...
   }
 }
```

Comment: And of course don't forget to clear cache after implementing `hook_form_alter()`.

Answer (score 1):

Think you are looking for the form alter hook here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x